# Dynamically Create Custom Post Type According to Relationship Another Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

It is hard explain what I am trying to build. So I will try to explain it via example.

**Custom Post Type** : Mobile

Assume that there are 4 mobile posts..

1. Nokia 6
2. Samsung S 7
3. Huawei P 10
4. Apple iPhone 7

**Custom Post Type** : Compare

Following compare posts should be auto created..

1. Nokia 6 vs Samsung S 7
2. Nokia 6 vs Huawei  P 10
3. Nokia 6 vs Apple iPhone 7
4. Samsung S 7 vs Huawei P 10
5. Samsung S 7 vs Apple iPhone 7
6. Huawei P 10 vs Apple iPhone 7

Every compare posts should be have two custom fields like `mobile1` and `mobile2` and it includes the post id of mobile post type.

---

Is it possible to build this type of site with WordPress?

I have some ideas build it using cron... I mean reading `Mobile Posts` and create compare posts.... But seems like it takes too much time... Is there any easy way?

Comment: the compare posts, should be created when there are 2 or more posts right?

Answer (score 4):

I would have the goal of appending the other device onto any existing permalink so you can compare one to the other, and vice versa. That's fully dynamic/automatic; i.e., requires no manual entry and no CRON job, etc.

So let's pretend you have:
`https://example.com/mobile-device-a/`

We want to add support for:
`https://example.com/mobile-device-a/compare/mobile-device-b/`
`https://example.com/mobile-device-b/compare/mobile-device-a/`

---

See: [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/)

Create a new endpoint so you can visit any mobile post type that already exists and simply add `.../compare/mobile-device-b/` onto the end of it, which can be used to transform the display of that particular post on-the-fly; i.e., you will look for the `/compare/mobile-device-b/` endpoint in your template(s).

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'compare', EP_PERMALINK );
} ); // This syntax requires PHP 5.4+.
```

See also: [WordPress Endpoint Introduction](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/)

---

Next, add some custom code in your template's `single.php` file, which will be responsible for detecting the use of the `/compare/mobile-device-b/` endpoint, and adjust the output accordingly.

I'll provide a quick example, showing how to run a sub-query and pull the content for the other device by slug. However, you'll no doubt need to customize this further and blend it into your theme and overall design goals.

```
<?php
$compare = get_query_var( 'compare' );
$compare = sanitize_key( $compare );

if ( is_singular( 'mobile' ) && $compare ) :
    $sub_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'mobile',
        'name'           => $compare,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ) );
?>
    <?php the_content(); // Of mobile-device-a. ?>

    <?php if ( $sub_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $sub_query->have_posts() ) : $sub_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_content(); // Of mobile-device-b. ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I upvote because I agree totaly that it's better to handle these URL dynamicaly instead of creating pages or custom posts.

Comment: Thanks :-) This is totally new thing for me. How should I change the content of `https://example.com/mobile-device-a/compare/mobile-device-b/`. I mean, it is programitically  generated content using custom fields of mobile a and mobile b. Where should I write that code? (Need to set SEO titile and meta....) How should I set them...? Thanks